# Does Intellij have a settings option or a plugin to collapse trailing closing brackets?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-folding

To illustrate, I would like a sample function like:

```
    fun before() {
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<SomeFragment>()
        scenario.onFragment {
            it.viewModel.selected.observe(it) { event ->
                selected = event?.content
            }
        }
    }
```

...to look like the following when it is not being edited:

```
    fun before() {
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<SomeFragment>()
        scenario.onFragment {
            it.viewModel.selected.observe(it) { event ->
                selected = event?.content }}}
```

And then, let's say, when cursor is placed withing the function's body or when an edit starts, the braces would be expanded automatically.

Comment: None of the Code Folding settings help you? (Editor -> General -> Code Folding)?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini nope